# Laravel 4 Model Events don't work with PHPUnit

Tags: phpunit, laravel, laravel-4

I build a model side validation in Laravel 4 with the `creating` Model Event :

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function isValid()
    {
        return Validator::make($this->toArray(), array('name' => 'required'))->passes();
    }

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function($user)
        {
            echo "Hello";
            if (!$user->isValid()) return false;
        });
    }
}
```

It works well but I have issues with PHPUnit. The two following tests are exactly the same but juste the first one pass :

```
class UserTest extends TestCase {

    public function testSaveUserWithoutName()
    {
        $count = User::all()->count();

        $user = new User;
        $saving = $user->save();

        assertFalse($saving);                       // pass
        assertEquals($count, User::all()->count()); // pass
    }

    public function testSaveUserWithoutNameBis()
    {
        $count = User::all()->count();

        $user = new User;
        $saving = $user->save();

        assertFalse($saving);                       // fail
        assertEquals($count, User::all()->count()); // fail, the user is created
    }
}
```

If I try to create a user twice in the same test, it works, but it's like if the binding event is present only in the first test of my test class. The `echo "Hello";` is printed only one time, during the first test execution.

I simplify the case for my question but you can see the problem : I can't test several validation rules in different unit tests. I try almost everything since hours but I'm near to jump out the windows now ! Any idea ?

Comment: Read https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1181

Comment: Thank you. Finally, Model Events are not easily testable. I solve my issue with that trick : I call `User::boot()` in my `setUp()` method.

Comment: I prefer to use `User::observe(new UserObserver)`, this way you can test `UserObserver` on it's own.

Comment: @AlexandreButynski I did the same, in the end it's a concise and catch-all solution for this issue for which a proper fix doesn't seem to be coming. Hopefully this is doable thanks to the `__callStatic` method on Eloquent models (`Model::boot` is `protected`), it saves us the hassle of defining a public method on our models just to make them testable. Thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is well documented in Github. See comments above that explains it further.

I've modified one of the 'solutions' in Github to automatically reset all model events during the tests. Add the following to your TestCase.php file.

**app/tests/TestCase.php**

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->resetEvents();
}


private function resetEvents()
{
    // Get all models in the Model directory
    $pathToModels = '/app/models';   // <- Change this to your model directory
    $files = File::files($pathToModels);

    // Remove the directory name and the .php from the filename
    $files = str_replace($pathToModels.'/', '', $files);
    $files = str_replace('.php', '', $files);

    // Remove "BaseModel" as we dont want to boot that moodel
    if(($key = array_search('BaseModel', $files)) !== false) {
        unset($files[$key]);
    }

    // Reset each model event listeners.
    foreach ($files as $model) {

        // Flush any existing listeners.
        call_user_func(array($model, 'flushEventListeners'));

        // Reregister them.
        call_user_func(array($model, 'boot'));
    }
}
```

Comment: It solves my issue in a more generic way than my basic trick (just add one line like `User::boot()` for each model) but it lets me puzzled for two reasons : it add a bunch of weird code in my TestCase class and it parses files before each test (which could cause performance issues)...

Comment: Needs to test if the model extends Model first though, sometimes they might not have flushEventListeners method.

Answer (score 1):

I have my models in subdirectories so I edited @TheShiftExchange code a bit

```
//Get all models in the Model directory
$pathToModels = '/path/to/app/models';
$files = File::allFiles($pathToModels);

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $fileName = $file->getFileName();
    if (!ends_with($fileName, 'Search.php') && !starts_with($fileName, 'Base')) {
        $model = str_replace('.php', '', $fileName);
        // Flush any existing listeners.
        call_user_func(array($model, 'flushEventListeners'));
        // Re-register them.
        call_user_func(array($model, 'boot'));
    }
}
```