# Laravel eloquent model reset booted property during unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit

I have a boot method on a class that extends from Eloquent's base model class. I want to run some unit tests and I need it to fire on each test.  Unfortunately,  the class ID index is persisting for the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::$booted` property which is set in the constructor that I extend from - so it only works for the first test. I've tried adjusting a few phpunit's flags - I tried process isolation - nothing seems to work.

**Is there a way I can reset this property so each test can fire my boot method?**

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php
public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
{
    if ( ! isset(static::$booted[get_class($this)])) <-- Keeps persisting
    {
        static::$booted[get_class($this)] = true;

        static::boot();
    }

    ...
}


app\models\Foo.php
class Foo extends Model {
    ...

    protected static function boot() { <-- first test to execute wins, all other calls get skipped
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ahh - just a tad more research and the answer is revealed!

My question is basically a duplicate of this question [Laravel 4 Model Events don't work with PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428050/laravel-4-model-events-dont-work-with-phpunit?rq=1), which references this [thread](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1181#issuecomment-32433256) on github for the solution